# Anyone know what this could be? Its from a holiday themed puzzle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, visual

[image]

The arrows point to the 4th and 6th blocks in the puzzle.

Comment: it looks like "taffy". Could you upload image including 4th and 6th block?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Is this from an ongoing contest of some sort, or a homework assignment?

Comment: Also, is the image meant to have the word displayed horizontally?

Comment: I wondered the same myself, @boboquack but then assumed that since the 5 is also rotated, that this was just an artifact of unwanted rotation that sometimes occurs on pictures taken on a mobile phone.

Comment: @Phylyp You can never be sure with rebuses.

Answer (score 7):

My answer doesn't relate to the adjacent puzzles, but could it be:

> [Taffy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taffy_(candy)) [pulling](http://www.exploratorium.edu/cooking/candy/taffy-story.html)

Edit: added explanation:

> Taffy is a sweet that is often made at home, and the act of pulling the taffy makes the sweet softer. 
>  The arrows at either end of the word 'taffy' make me thing of pulling (stretching) it, which leads to *'pulling the taffy'*, hence *'taffy pulling'*.